# Braces in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

I'm going to set ComboBox's DataSource to ProjectTypes in my database with the following code:

```
private void GetAllProjectTypes()
{
    var query = db.ProjectTypes.Select(pt => new { pt.Id, pt.Title });
    cmbProjectTypes.DisplayMember = "Title";
    cmbProjectTypes.ValueMember = "Id";
    cmbProjectTypes.DataSource = query;
}
```

The problem is that after binding the ComboBox two braces come to the ComboBox. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

You can see the braces in the image above.

Comment: This looks strange ! Have you tried `.Select(pt => new { Id = pt.Id, Title = pt.Title }).ToList();`

Comment: @user3185569, I did what you said, but not worked. The result is like the image in my question.

Comment: The code is working fine for me. Try adding setting the data source to `query.ToList()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields need to be named: You're just seeing the result of ToString()

```
 var query = db.ProjectTypes.Select(pt => new { Id= pt.Id, Title= pt.Title });
```

Comment: I did what you said, but not worked. The result likes the image in my question.

Comment: Strange... are you sure you've recompiled it. It does exactly whats expected on my machine.

Comment: The anonymous type automatically uses `Id` and `Title` as the property names, no need to name them explicitly.

Comment: I found the reason, but so strange. There is also a GridView on the form that is bound when the user selects a project type from combobox. When I bind the Grid using custom class then braces appear in the combobox and when I bind the Grid using anonymous type then braces disappear. I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

And try this bit:

```
new { pt.Id, pt.Title }
```

Creates an anonymous type at runtime. therefore it's serialized not unlike JSON as displayed in your sample.
try to make your query like this maybe:

```
var query = db.ProjectTypes.Select(pt => string.Format("{0} - {1}", pt.Id, pt.Title));
```

Comment: This is not true. The default `.ToString()` of an anonymous type shows all the properties and values in Curly braces, but if you specify a property in Display Member then it should work fine. Just try it.

Comment: I don't want to show Id in ComboBox. As you can see from the question I want to show only the Title and need set Id as ValueMember!

Comment: Maybe you should just create a class for this purpose?

Comment: @MichaelThePotato, I also created a custom class for this purpose, but I don't know, it also didn't work.

Comment: Could you show us your XAML? is there a reason the query isn't saved as a member and bound to the control? it is usually ill-advised to bind via code.
Try using the ItemsSource instead of the DataSource!

Comment: @MichaelThePotato This is WinForms – no XAML, no data binding, no `ItemsSource`…